# want to fetch data from firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I can fetch all data but don't know how to go inside the nodes
and fetch values. Here is the structure of my database want to fetch all data

[image]

```
func fetchData(){
    ref = Database.database().reference()
    let userid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

    ref.child(Constants.NODE_MAINTENANCE).child(userid!).child(Constants.NODE_MAINTENANCE_DATE).child(self.lastMaintenanceDateLbl.text ?? "").observe(DataEventType.value) { (snap) in



        guard snap.exists()
            else {
                print("no data found at this date")
                AppUtils.showAlert(title: "Alert", message: "No data found at this date!", viewController: self)
                return}

//             let maintenanceType = snapshot.value as? [String] ?? [""]
//            print(maintenanceType)

        if let snapshot = snap.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot]{

            for snap in snapshot{

                let maintenanceType = snap.value as? [String:Any]
                for type in (maintenanceType?.values)!{
                    print(type)


                }


            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: That `for snap in snapshot{` looks like the correct approach to looping over all nodes under the maintenance date (e.g. `cabin`, `cardan`, etc). What is the problem with our current code? What does it print? And what did you expect (or want) it to print?

Comment: {
    "essuies_glace" = OK;
    "nettoyage_filter_cabin" = OK;
    "nettoyage_filter_moteur" = OK;
    proprete = OK;
    "temoins_securites" = OK;
}
{
    cardan1 = OK;
    cardan2 = OK;
    cardan3 = OK;
    date = "26-07-2018";
}
{
    comment = "Some comment";
    "upload_photo" = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/revagrotrasport.appspot.com/o/carroseries_images?alt=media&token=6de9aec1-b200-4ef9-b44a-3f73101dfc8b";
}
{
    ccb = OK;
    "man_barry" = OK;
}
{
    "ar_droit" = route;
    "arr_droit" = stop;
    "arr_gauche" = "the route";
    
}

Comment: but i want to inside these node and fetch these values for reference you can see image of my firebase data struchere

Comment: If you want to go one level deeper, you will need to loop over the children of `snapshot` too (just like you now loop over the children of `snap`).

Comment: elf.ref.child("cabin").childByAutoId().observe(.value, with: { (cabinSnap) in
                            guard cabinSnap.exists() else{
                                return
                            }
                            
                            if let cabinItems = cabinSnap.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot]{
                                for snap in cabinItems{
                                    let cabinData = snap.value as? [String:Any]
                                    print(cabinData)
                                }
                }
            })

Comment: here is the code for fetch children. is am on right track??

Comment: Please don't post large chunks of code into the comments. It becomes hard to read. Click the edit link under your question and add it in there (typically marked with **update** or something like that).

Comment: self.ref.child("cabin").childByAutoId().observe(.value, with: { (cabinSnap) in

Comment: guard cabinSnap.exists() else{
                                return
                            }

Comment: if let cabinItems = cabinSnap.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot]{

Comment: for snap in cabinItems{
                                    let cabinData = snap.value as? [String:Any]
                                    print(cabinData)
                                }
                            }
                        })

Comment: Please don't post in comments. It's impossible to see what you are doing. Update your question with the additional code.